# Why am I getting precompiling assets failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I typically make updates to my production Ruby on Rails application and today I updated some security vulnerabilities with gem files, pushed them to my Github repo and then did a `git push heroku master` and received the following errors:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:
remote:
remote:          config.secret_key = '<hash>'
remote:
remote:        Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key....
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
```

Not sure if there is a connection between `actionview -v 5.1.6.2` that I recently updated to and this error.

Comment: in devise.rb file add secret key , you can generate secret key with `rake secret`

Comment: @Vishal, the prompt gave me the hash to use or was that just an example?

Comment: yes you have to use that hash and add it to devise.rb file

Comment: @Vishal, I added the hash and was able to push to heroku, but now the application is broken in production with lowlevel error occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open config/initializers/devise.rb file

it contain line

```
config.secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

If you find this line is commented, uncomment in. If it don't have any secret key find your secret key by running `rake secret`.

Best place to put your secret_key is enviornment variables. So try change line in devise.rb file like below.

```
config.secret_key = Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base
```

Open config/secrets.rb file

```
production:
  secret_key_base: ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY']
```

In Heroku you can set DEVISE_SECRET_KEY in config variables.